# use htaccess to rewrite subfolder in drupal

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, kohana

So there is a drupal installation with a subfolder with kohana 3 in it.  Trying to redirect the URL to something much more clean

RewriteRule ^newpage$ /registered_affiliates/index.php/affiliates/splash

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please don't do this in your .htaccess

there is a routes file in ko2 or bootstrap file in ko3 where you can disable the ugly "index.php" and set the routes like you wish them to look like to the right controllers.
if you remove the index.php from your links you will need to use the default .htaccess file with the right `RewriteBase`